# Show that if $\int_{Q}f$ exists, then $\int_{y\in B}f(x,y)$ exists for $x\in A-D$, where $D$ is a set of measure zero in $\mathbb{R}^k$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, vector-analysis

[image]

I know that this problem has already been posted here [$Q=A\times B$. if $\int_Q f$ exists, then $\int_{y\in B}f(x,y)$ exists for $x\in A-D$, where $D$ is a set of measure zero in $\mathbb{R^k}$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1483438/q-a-times-b-if-int-q-f-exists-then-int-y-in-bfx-y-exists-for-x-in?rq=1) and here [if $\int_Q f$ exists then $\int_{y \in B} f(x, y)$ exists for each $x \in A − D$, where $D$ is of measure zero.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2511584/if-int-q-f-exists-then-int-y-in-b-fx-y-exists-for-each-x-in-a-%E2%88%92-d/2511604#2511604), but the answers do not seem clear to me and a post has no solution. In the second post that I mention, they give a first answer that I do not understand because they use the theory of measure a lot and the truth is that I am a beginner in this and I only have the basic taboo of the measure available, the second answer seems very understandable but unfinished, what else could I do with respect to that second answer? Could anyone help me, please?

Could you help me understand this test that I found? Thank you very much. I do not understand why $f(x)\geq 0$.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the solution it is better to name $g(x)=\overline{I}(x)-\underline{I}(x)$ insted of $f(x)=\overline{I}(x)-\underline{I}(x),$ since it is confusing with the $f$ of the statement (it is not the same function). Note also that in the solution it is wrong (it says $f(x)=\underline{I}(x)-\overline{I}(x)$ and should be $f(x)=\overline{I}(x)-\underline{I}(x)$). We have $g(x)\geq 0$ for all $x$ by definition of upper and lower integrals (upper integral is always greater than lower integral).

PS: That is Munkres Analysis on Manifolds 13.2 right? You can also use 13.1(b) for this exercise, it is more straightforward.

Comment: Why exercise is easier by assuming 13.1 (b)?

Comment: Use exercise 13.1(b) with $f(x)=\underline{I}(x)$ and $g(x)=\overline{I}(x).$ Then $\underline{I}(x)\leq \overline{I}(x)$ and $\int_Qf=\int_A\underline{I}(x)=\int_A\overline{I}(x),$ so $\underline{I}(x)$ and $\overline{I}(x)$ agree except on a set of measure zero $D.$

Comment: How can I try exercise 13.1(b)?

Comment: Actually, don't know how to do it without some use of measure, as in here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/109923/integration-over-a-bounded-set